# MongoDB schema for timeseries with metadata

Tags: mongodb, schema, metadata, time-series

Which is the best way to store time series data for documents having metadata?

My object has metadata:

```
{
  _id: abcdefghijk,
  meta1: value1, 
  meta2: value2,
  tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3]
}
```

Each minute or hour, each object have some statistics:

```
{
  objectId: abcdefghijk,
  timestampt: 2014-01-01 00:00:00,
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
}
```

I need to:

- Get statistics of objects in a specific minute, hour, or greater, a period of time
- Filter objects by metadata
- Aggratations like sum/avg of all key1 values grouped by metadata meta1

I am looking for an advice of experienced users. If you have any questions, I would be glad to answer them and will appreciate your help.

Comment: That means that every hour you documents will be uploaded?

Comment: yes, hourly upload is fine for now. The main issue is how to get data by both time and metadata

Answer (score 1):

A lot of best practice for dealing with time-series data is contained in the MongoDB document [Pre-Aggregated Reports](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/). Typically, you will use some or all of the following patterns:

- Bucketing by day (or some other period) using upserts
- Pre-aggregating summary values (eg. $inc) at various levels (eg. minute, hour, day) by using in-place updates, whenever each new event/tick is consumed, thus enabling subsequent very fast queries of aggregated data
- Pre-allocating new bucket documents, to reduce ingestion rate drop off
- Use Intra Document Hierarchy, to also reduce ingestion rate drop off

Comment: Thank you! My challenge here is that the metadata is big (20 fields) and I can not duplicate it for every stats (even daily stats)

Comment: If you don't want to store the metadata once per "bucket" (eg once per day), have one collection for just metadata and one collection for the pure time series part of the data, and apply the above patterns on the latter.

Comment: Can you also help to show me how to query get all the stats of objects with day = $today and meta1 = $value1?